# Delaying Kafka Streams consuming

Tags: java, kotlin, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I'm trying to use **Kafka Streams** (i.e. not a simple Kafka Consumer) to read from a retry topic with events that have previously failed to process. I wish to consume from the retry topic, and if processing still fails (for example, if an external system is down), I wish to put the event back on the retry topic. Thus I don't want to keep consuming immediately, but instead wait a while before consuming, in order to not flood the systems with messages that are temporarily unprocessable.

Simplified, the code currently does this, and I wish to add a delay to it.

```
fun createTopology(topic: String): Topology {
    val streamsBuilder = StreamsBuilder()

    streamsBuilder.stream<String, ArchivalData>(topic, Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), ArchivalDataSerde()))
        .peek { key, msg -> logger.info("Received event for key $key : $msg") }
        .map { key, msg -> enrich(msg) }
        .foreach { key, enrichedMsg -> archive(enrichedMsg) }

    return streamsBuilder.build()
}
```

I have tried to use Window Delay to set this up, but have not managed to get it to work. I could of course do a sleep inside a `peek`, but that would leave a thread hanging and does not sound like a very clean solution.

The exact details of how the delay would work is not terribly important to my use case. For example, all of these would work fine:

1. All events on the topic in the past `x` seconds are all consumed at once. After it begins / finishes to consume, the stream waits `x` seconds before consuming again
2. Every event is processed `x` seconds after being put on the topic
3. The stream consumes messages with a delay of `x` seconds between every event

I would be very grateful if someone could provide a few lines of Kotlin or Java code that would accomplish any of the above.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot really pause reading from the input topic using Kafka Streams—the only way to "delay" would be to call a "sleep", but as you mentioned, that blocks the whole thread and is not a good solution.

However, what you can do is to use a stateful processor, e.g., `process()` (with attached state store) instead of `foreach()`. If the retry fails, you don't put the record back into the input topic, but you put it into the store and also register a punctuation with desired retry delay. If the punctuation fires, you retry and if the retry succeeds, you delete the entry from the store and cancel the punctuation; otherwise, you wait until the punctuation fires again.

Comment: Thanks! However, I have several `map` steps (simplified to just one in my example though), all of which can fail. Would every `map` be replaced by `process` instead?

Comment: You can do different things: Either, collapse everything into a single `process()` call (seems to be the easiest solution), or start with a `transform()` that adds a record into the store, and have a final `transform()` (or `process()`) that removes a record from the store if all steps in between succeeded (note, that you can share a store by passing it into both `transforms()`).

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax  please explain what you mean by   register a punctuation with desired retry delay

Comment: Not sure what your exact question is. If you don't know what punctuations are, check out the docs: https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/streams/developer-guide/processor-api.html#defining-a-stream-processor

Comment: What happens to the punctuation, if the stream application crashes and restarts? Will that "trigger" disappear?

Comment: Well, yes and no. It's not persistent anywhere if a punctuation was registered, but on re-start, `Processor#init(...)` will be called again, so a punctuation should be re-registered automatically.